# SSL encryption work only in content?

Tags: tls

Can SSL encrypt the relative path I would like to visit in a site?

If I would like to make a login system with GET instead of POST, can SSL encrypt the part "?username=user1&password=pass1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under HTTPS, the entire request - HTTP headers and body - are protected by SSL.  As @aj-henderson points out, the server name portion of the URI may be leaked by DNS, and of course the server IP address is indisputably visible to someone capturing the traffic.

I think you may be confusing SSL and the historic difference between GET and POST with respect to  **logging** - the URI and query string may (and probably will) be logged by the web server and any intervening proxy servers in the case of GET; in the case of POST, the URI may be logged but the query string will *generally* not be.  (It's *possible* but not usually done)

(And, of course, HTTPS doesn't protect against what the server logs, because by definition the server decrypts).

Answer (score 1):

SSL does protect the actual files being accessed.  It actually occurs at the IP level, but the main part of the URL leaks via DNS.  This is why you can only have one SSL cert per IP address, because until the connection is established, the server has no idea what is being requested unless SNI is used (which still just provides host name during the connection being established).

Comment: Actually with SNI that last bit isn't try anymore - with SNI, the hostname can be included before the certificate is required: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI

Comment: @DouglasLeeder - wasn't aware of that, thanks for the heads up.  Updated the answer accordingly.